# Is it ok to keep primers at 4 degrees?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, bioinorganic-chemistry

I reconstitute my primers in nuclease free water ( no sterilised) this morning and I forgot them at 4 degrees, acording to the instructions, they should be storage at -20 after the reconstitution. I am wondering if it will affect to have them overnight at 4 degrees, just for one day.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no problem here. Primers will [degrade only very slowly at 4 degrees](https://eu.idtdna.com/pages/education/decoded/article/storing-oligos-7-things-you-should-know) and even at room temperature leaving them out overnight would not degrade them enough to be of practical consequence. In fact, if you're using them today it's probably *better* to have stored them at 4 degrees than -20 because repeated freeze/thaw cycles will also degrade primers.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is not a problem. I keep my working stocks at 4°C until they are finished to avoid freeze-thaw cycles and better convenience and they work all the time. I also dissolve my primers in pure water, not in TE.

Long-term storage of stocks should be done at -20.